# Why Material Button has padding at the top and bottom? Cannot get rid of it

Tags: android, android-button, material-components-android

No matter if I set padding to 0dp, it's always there.

All these properties in Material Button are so confusing and there's no proper documentation for it.

Reproduce it:
Using theme `Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar`, put a button in a layout, it will have that padding at top and bottom.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain better the question? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Just updated the description, basically using a MaterialComponents theme